# Writing a function to clean string data and rename columns

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, user-defined-functions, stringr

I am writing a function to be applied to many individual matrices. Each matrix has 5 columns of string text. I want to remove a piece of one string which matches the string inside another element exactly, then apply a couple more stringr functions, transform it into a data frame, then rename the columns and in the last step I want to add a number to the end of each column name, since I will apply this to many matrices and need to identify the columns later.

This is very similar to another function I wrote so I can't figure out why it won't work. I tried running each line individually by filling in the inputs like this and it works perfectly:

```
Review1[,4] <- str_remove(Review1[,4], Review1[,3])
Review1[,4] <- str_sub(Review1[,4], 4, -4)
Review1[,4] <- str_trim(Review1[,4], "both")
Review1 <- as.data.frame(Review1)
colnames(Review1) <- c("Title", "Rating", "Date", "User", "Text")
Review1 <- Review1 %>% rename_all(paste0, 1)
```

But when I run the function nothing seems to happen at all.

```
Transform_Reviews <- function(x, y, z, a) {
  x[,y] <- str_remove(x[,y], x[,z])
  x[,y] <- str_sub(x[,y], 4, -4)
  x[,y] <- str_trim(x[,y], "both")
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  colnames(x) <- c("Title", "Rating", "Date", "User", "Text")
  x <- x %>% rename_all(paste0, a)
}

Transform_Reviews(Review1, 4, 3, 1)
```

This is the only warning message I get. I also receive this when I run the str_remove function individually, but it still changes the elements. But it changes nothing when I run the UDF.

Warning messages:
1: In stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  ... :
  empty search patterns are not supported

This is an example of the part of Review1 that I'm working with.

```
     [,3]           [,4]                                               
[1,] "6 April 2014" "By Copnovelist on 6 April 2014" 
[2,] "18 Dec. 2015" "By kenneth bell on 18 Dec. 2015"
[3,] "26 May 2015"  "By Simon.B :-) on 26 May 2015"  
[4,] "22 July 2013" "By Lilla Lukacs on 22 July 2013"
```

This is what I want the output to look like:

```
Date1            User1
1  6 April 2014  Copnovelist
2  18 Dec. 2015  kenneth bell
3  26 May 2015   Simon.B :-)
4  22 July 2013  Lilla Lukacs
```

Comment: Can you make this post reproducible my including `dput(Review1)` ?  Also include expected output for the same.

Comment: I added some additional information. Hope that helps!

Comment: In your UDF, can you add in last line `return(x)` and then try running it. See if it works?

Comment: You know what, my only issue is I wasn't using an assignment operator when I tried to use the function. That is embarrassing, even for a beginner like me! Thanks for taking a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

I realized I just needed to use an assignment operator to see my function work.

```
Review1 <- Transform_Reviews(Review1, 4, 3, 1)
```